# Unexpected behaviour in Hive queries with date comparisons

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp

I have a hive table with only one column 'datecol' which is a string type and contains some dates

```
2017-08-29 23:25:16.0
2017-08-04 23:25:40.0
2017-08-04 23:25:40.0
2017-08-29 23:25:07.0
2017-08-29 23:25:53.0
2016-01-09 09:25:20.0
2017-08-18 03:25:24.0
2017-08-18 03:25:24.0
2017-08-29 23:25:26.0
2017-08-04 23:25:40.0
```

I am running the following queries in hive shell.

```
select count(*) from somedates where datecol > '2017-01-01';
```

output : 9

```
select count(*) from somedates where to_date(datecol) > to_date('2017-01-01');
```

output : 9

```
select count(*) from somedates where datecol > to_date('2017-01-01');
```

output : 0

I understand that in the last query a string is being compared with date object, but if I run the query

```
select '2017-01-01' > to_date('2016-01-01')
```

output : true

This means hive is able to compare string and date objects correctly.

Then why isn't it able to do the same in the third query? Did I miss something?

Comment: what is the output of the query: SELECT to_date('2017-01-01'). ?

Comment: @Alex its 2017-01-01

Answer (score 0):

```
I created table and i performed all steps which you provided above and i got 9 
as a result for  all those 3 query which you mentioned above.

If you are using HDP, you can use this query as "select count(*) from 
somedates where datecol > to_date('2017-01-01 00:00:00')"

I hope it will work for you. You can refer this link 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92359/timestamp-string-comparison-in-hive.html
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something you are missing. I reproduced that and it returned me 9 for all cases.

In first case you compare string to string. That is why 2017-01 part is less then 2017-08 for 9 times and 2017 is larger than 2016 for 1 time.

In second case you compare the dates and it is obvious that according to date comparision logic you get 9 positive values.

The third case performs **to_date** and compares it as a string, which would be similar to the 1-st case.

You either using some old defected library or miss something in your question. Try to update Hive to more up-to-date version.

Comment: This is strange. I am using Hive 2.3.0.